# While loop makes my program to not respond while running

Tags: c#

I have a little problem.
While loop make my program to not respond (while executing).
How can I make the program to work even when the while loop is active? Or when the program is running that script?

Comment: we will need code. Usually this means that your loop is infinite and is running on your program's main thread

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek - Not necessarily infinite. Just long-running enough to be noticeable to the user.

Comment: yes, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a non-blocking loop, you should put that in a separate thread.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You should post an example of this solution. It would make your answer much more useful.

Comment: `while(found < need_to_found) { do stuff }` and it needs to do many calculations, that take some time... i want to put a progress bar or something..
the code is write ok, but how can i make the program to be still functional while "while loop" is running?

Comment: Have a look at the post at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/; perhaps that will give you an idea for a solution of your problem.